# How to grep only if pattern1 and pattern2 matches in consecutive lines

Tags: grep

I have a file like below:

```
city-italy
good food
bad climate
-
city-india
bad food
normal climate
-
city-brussel
normal dressing
stylish cookings
good food
-
```

Question - I want to grep `city` and `food`, for which "food" is "bad".

For example - 
for the above question, i need a grep command to get a answer like below

```
city-india
bad food
```

Please help me like, how i will get pattern 1 and pattern 2 grepped only if both succeeds parallely.

i mean both pattern should match and it should grep in the following line.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with pipes - `grep -A1 city <filename> | grep -B1 "bad food"` or `cat filename | grep -A1 city | grep -B1 "bad food"` (or any other stream source for the pipe)

Comment: Good one, showing both possibilities. Note you can avoid the `cat` part with `grep -A1 city filename`.

Answer (score 2):

If the city name is guaranteed to come before the food quality (any other info in between is allowed):

```
sed -n -e '/^city/h' -e '/bad food/{x;G;p}' input
```

Which keeps the name of each city in the hold buffer and prints the last city name when matches bad food.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is ensured, you can use directly the command `grep` with OR:

```
grep -e "city" -e "food" FILE_INPUT
```

Then hopefully the city will follow by its food feature at following.

The result looks like:

```
city-italy
good food
city-india
bad food
city-brussel
good food
```

You can change your pattern to get a more filtered result.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here's a "robust" alternative (cuz I'm into that):

```
grep -x -e'city-.*' -e'good food' -e'bad food' -e'-' | tr \\n \| | sed -e's/|-|/\n/g' | grep -xe'[^|]\+|[^|]\+' | grep -e'|bad food$' | tr \| \\n
```

---

### Explanation

1. `grep -x -e'city-.*' -e'good food' -e'bad food' -e'-'`: only keep the lines that contain a "city line", a "food line" (either good or bad), or a "separator line" (the food line expression could be better, I know), the `-x` argument to `grep` will make it return a line *only if the whole line matches the given expression* (incidentally, this first stage makes the whole pipe not choke on differently-sized "registers"),
2. `tr \\n \|`: turn newlines into pipes (you can use any character that does not appear in the original file, pipe works, so does a colon, you get the idea),
3. `sed -e's/|-|/\n/g'`: replace the `|-|` string by a newline (this are the places we know a "register" ends, since we only kept the datums we're interested in and the separators, we know that now we have each of our "registers" in a single line, with their fields separated by pipes),
4. `grep -xe'[^|]\+|[^|]\+'`: only keep lines containing *exactly* two fields (ie. the city and food fields),
5. `grep -e'|bad food$'`: keep only lines ending in `|bad food`,
6. `tr \| \\n`: turn pipes back into newlines (nb. this is just here so that the output conforms to the question's specification, it's not really needed, nor preferred in my opinion).

### Partial outputs

After `grep -x -e'city-.*' -e'good food' -e'bad food' -e'-'`:

```
city-italy
good food
-
city-india
bad food
-
city-brussel
good food
-
```

After `tr \\n \|`:

```
city-italy|good food|-|city-india|bad food|-|city-brussel|good food|-|
```

After `sed -e's/|-|/\n/g'`:

```
city-italy|good food
city-india|bad food
city-brussel|good food
```

After `grep -xe'[^|]\+|[^|]\+'`: *idem*, since we don't have a "city line" without a "food line" in the example given, nor a register containing two "city lines" and a "food line", nor a register containing a "city line" and two "food lines", nor... you get the picture,

After `grep -e'|bad food$'`:

```
city-india|bad food
```

After `tr \| \\n`:

```
city-india
bad food
```

### Why is this more "robust"?

The input file basically consists of different "registers", each containing a variable number of "fields", but instead of having them in an "horizontal" format, we find them in a "vertical" one, ie. one field per line with a lone `-` separating whole registers.

The pipe above supports any amount of fields in each register, it only assumes that:

1. Registers are separated by a lone `-`,
2. The "city fields" are all of the form `city-*`,
3. The "food fields" are either `good food` or `bad food`,
4. If at all existent, "city" fields appear *before* "food" fields.

(this last one I find particularly hard to relax, at least in a "normal"-ish pipe like the one given).

I does ***not*** assume that:

1. Each register has a "city" *and* a "food" field,
2. Each register has *only* "city" and "food" fields.

### Disclaimer

I'm not claiming this is in any way better than any of the other answers, it's just that I can't do `sed` or `awk` to save my own life, and often find pipes like this are helpful in understanding how the file gets filtered and transformed.

All in all, it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

To get city with `bad food` using `gnu awk` (due to RS)

```
awk '/bad food/ {print RS $1}' RS="city" file
city-india
```

Answer (score 0):

another awk line:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\n";RS="-"FS}/bad food/{print $1,$2}' file
city-india
bad food
```